# Core Data - Crash while listening for notification NSManagedObjectContextDidSave

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data

Seeing a strange crash while listening

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contextDidSave(_:)), name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: nil)

   @objc private func contextDidSave(_ notification: Notification) {
       print(notification)
   }

However, keeping below line and calling something else inside it not causing any issues.
Below code will work fine as we are not printing or consuming objects

   if let updatedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<User>, !updatedObjects.isEmpty { 
        myMethod()
   }
```

Already debugged by using NSZombiesEnabled, InstrumentsWithCoreData, Exception Breakpoints,ThreadSanatizer, "Arguments Passed on Launch" in -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

Unable to get why it's happening. However i thought it's of property so I printed all property 1 by 1 it worked fine for me.

As per as my knowledge it's happening because of combination of Swift and Obj-C

It's a huge project so I am not sure  what can be done?
Is there a way that I can get more info about object via it's reference mat be object name or another information, Somehow?

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff80634470'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e5eb94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e4286c ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e44b58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreData                            0x00007fff23a816c9 -[NSManagedObject _descriptionValues] + 1566
    6   CoreData                            0x00007fff23a819f1 -[NSManagedObject description] + 261
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e60600 -[NSSet descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 416
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e37858 -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 1416
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff259698c9 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 55
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23dc7281 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 12737
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23dc8ea5 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 133
    12  CoreData                            0x00007fff23a324a4 _NSCoreDataLog + 248
    13  CoreData                            0x00007fff239f7e80 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _didSaveChanges] + 2893
    14  CoreData                            0x00007fff239ee7d6 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 4166
    15  ***********                          0x00000001076e8db3 __31-[MyStorageManager saveContext]_block_invoke + 83
    16  CoreData                            0x00007fff23a0338d developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 154
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f252e8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f260d97 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1149
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1869 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9c3b9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2041
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    24   ***********                          0x00000001074dc882 main + 146
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff520ce1fd start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Looking at the backtrace, the error looks like it would also happen whenever you used `print(myManagedObject)` - that might make it easier to track down. Also, its recommended that you specify a context in the object field when listening to that notification, otherwise you will get notifications from internal frameworks that also use core data.

Comment: Not exactly whenever, it's like only while listening notification. It's causing issue, my app is working fine. I am fetching the data and storing also.

Its recommended that you specify a context in the object, yeah I Agee with this, I tried using with both approaches still receiving crash.

Comment: It's hard to say but the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error is a strong indication that something is getting unexpectedly deallocated while references to it still exist. In this case a managed object appears to be getting deallocated even though the app still has a reference to that object.